# Asus PCE-AC51 wireless network card boot up issue

Tags: boot, networking, asus, intel

I just bought an Asus PCE-AC51 wireless network card .  I have a desktop computer with a

Intel DQ35JO Motherboard, Intel Core 2 Duo E6550 CPU 2.33 Ghz.

I am running Ubuntu linux 19.04

My problem is

1)  On a computer that I already had setup and working fine with the onboard LAN,  the  computer boots and OS desktop appears without this card. When I put the card in the desktop doesn’t appear meaning it shows the purple screen with
Untuntu .... 
but doesn't go beyond that

2)  If I attempt to reinstall Ubuntu 19.04 desktop on the exact same computer, surprisingly, the network card is recognized in install process and I was able to connect to my network. But after the install is done a reboot is required and the desktop doesn’t appear.
I thought it may be a conclict with the onboard lan but in the BIOS it can't be disable :-(

Please advise.

Thank you,
John

Comment: i discovered was able to install and boot to a desktop with this motherboard & pci card

Comment: I forgot to mention that was with  Centos 7

Comment: fwiw, I'm seeing a similar issue with this card on arch